# OutputStream received by servlet as empty

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets, httpurlconnection

this simple post method didn't send anything to server(servlet). I can get, but i can't post!

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://ipaddr:8080/work/wh");
                HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                client.setRequestMethod("POST");
                client.setDoOutput(true);
                client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                client.connect();

                OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
                pw.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                pw.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                pw.println(new Float(5.6));
                pw.println(new Integer(3));
                pw.println(new Integer(2));
                pw.println(new Integer(32));
                pw.println(new Integer(2));
                pw.close();
                outputStream.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("text", "ux " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

at server side if i tried to read any line  `new Scanner(request.getInputStream()).nextLine();`  I get

> NoSuchElementException: No line found

what do you think might be the problem?

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is not 'void'.

Comment: i mean i get void object inputsteam has no data

Comment: Code is not in MCVE format and the cause is not visible in the information provided so far, so we can only give educated guesses. Are you aware that the request body will be empty when it's already (implicitly) been parsed by the server beforehand? E.g. calling `request.getParameter()` will cause it to instantly be parsed. Nonetheless, why don't you just follow the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format as used by HTML forms and natively supported by servlet API? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2793150

Answer (score -1):

Try flushing PrintWritter/Outputstream before closing them.

Comment: do you even know what does flush do - do you

Comment: forces any buffered output bytes to be written out.